# How to shutdown an ExecutorService properly?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a `ScheduledExecutorService scheduler` that `scheduleAtFixRate` a few tasks.
Each task has a `ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize)`.
These executors will execute sub-tasks. I have a shutdown hook that calls `scheduler.shutdown()` and `scheduler.shutdownNow()`

```
    scheduler.shutdown();

    try {
        scheduler.awaitTermination(threadTimeout, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
```

1. But will that shutdown all the threads in sub-tasks? My understanding is that doing so only send interruption signal to threads
   but it's up to the thread to stop when it can.
2. When I terminate my program with Ctrl+C, sometimes I see (based on the output log) my shutdown hook runs, other times I don't.
   How to guarantee smooth shutdown in my settings?
3. Is it necessary to have some sort of flag in each task and alter it when shutdown to signal threads to stop or calling `scheduler.shutdown()` is enough?